Get mouse position on PDF document displayed in PDFium viewer on click
I have a Windows Forms application where a user is supposed to open a PDF, then click on any place on said PDF and a stamp should appear where the user has clicked.
I am using PdfRenderer from PDFiumViewer for rendering the PDF and iText7 to create the stamp.
One things I struggle with, is getting the mouse position relative to the displayed PDF.
PDF is zoomable, and you can scroll up and down. For now, I have tried this:
 private void pdfRenderer_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     var args = (MouseEventArgs)e;
     clickX = args.X;
     clickY = args.Y;
     zoomFactor = pdfRenderer.Zoom;            

     float pdfX = (float)(clickX / zoomFactor);
     float pdfY = (float)(clickY / zoomFactor);

where pdfX and pdfY are coordinates inside PDF. But this does not work. Another solution I thought of, is maybe always resizing the renderer, so that renderer width is always equal to PDF page width, but not sure if this is the right way. Is it possible to implement this idea, or is it better to do it somehow else?

your question does not clear on how does not work. The first idea i got is the pdf origin (0,0) is on the left bottom corner. windows origin (0,0) is on the top left. so the mouse coord on the Y is could be wrong. if i am right the Y coord is mirrored.

@lork6  Right now, basically, it shifts almost always to the right on X axis. As to height, if I do not invert Y, then it works in the lower part of the document (as in places the stamp on the same height), but when I click on top - it still places the stamp somewhere bottom. If I mirror Y, then the upper part of the PDF page works, but if I click in lower part - stamp still appears at the top.

x could be that the control is 400 in px but the pdf is 600 px. In load if you do not calculate the zoom factor then it will shift. The y is the same. plus you need to calculate the pdfHegith - (args.Y * zoomfactor)

what value do you get on pdfRenderer.Zoom when you zoom in? i would imagen you get on zoom is zoom > 1. if you zoom out then zoom < 1.

I was able to finally get it working.
private void pdfRenderer_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var args = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    _clickX = e.Location.X;
    _clickY = e.Location.Y;

    Point DevicePoint = new Point((int)_clickX, (int)_clickY);
    PdfPoint PDFpoint = pdfRenderer.PointToPdf(DevicePoint);

    float pdfX = PDFpoint.Location.X;
    float pdfY = PDFpoint.Location.Y;

This gives you X and Y coordinates on PDF file. Works with different zoom factors and multiple pages loaded.
